# Invoke-Sqlcmd : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OutputAs'

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a powershell script that will run a sql command and output the results as a dataset.

**PowerShell:**

```
(Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database 'STARS' -Username $Username -Password $Password -query $sqlCommand -OutputAs DataSet)
```

I am getting the following error when I try to run the script.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OutputAs'.
At D:\PipelinePowerShellScripts\UnitTests\Generate.Auth.Tokens.ps1:163 char:132
+ ... me $Username -Password $Password -query $sqlCommand -OutputAs DataSet ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

**PowerShell Version:**

> Major.Minor.Build.Revision
>
> 5.1.14409.1005

When I run this script on my local if runs without issues. However trying to run this on a Windows Server 2012 R2 returns the error above.

Comment: Is `$sqlCommand` a literal command or a path to a `.sql` file? If its a command, try a simpler command than the one you wish to execute, for testing purposes. Is the command formatted correctly? What happens if you rearrange `-query` and `-OutputAs`? If you remove `-OutputAs` entirely, do you get results in the default format of DataRows?

Comment: When you run `get-command Invoke-Sqlcmd` do you only get one result? What is the version of that? I have an older version that does not have that parameter. I have PSv5 and thats news to me if it comes stanard as I have to import a module for mine.

Comment: `Cmdlet | Invoke-Sqlcmd | 21.1.18121 | SqlServer `

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because the module has been completely re-written for powershell v5.
You need to run the `get-help invoke-sqlcmd -full` on that server to see the available methods in that version.

[HERE](https://www.sqlshack.com/learning-powershell-and-sql-server-introduction/) - you have it better explained ("two products" section)

I think that the easiest way would be to upgrade the powershell on the servers to 5+ and to use the new SQL Module.

Comment: It has `-OutputAs <OutputType>` when I run that command which is what I have

Comment: Can you tell us what powershell version do you have on that 2012-R2 server and version of MSSQL client installed (if any ) ? That would help trying to replicate