# Why isn't -OutputAs parameter of Invoke-Sqlcmd valid?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm getting this error in my powershell script:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OutputAs'.
At powershell_script_name.ps1:317 char:97
+ ... nce $strSserver -Database $strDatabase -Query $query -OutputAs Datatab ...
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument (:) [Invoke-Sqllcmd], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound, MicrosoftSqlserver.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

- SqlServer module version: 21.1.18256
- Powershell version: 5.1.14393.4583
- [Environment]::Is64BitProcess: True
- SQL Server version: 2016 Developer x64 (13.0.6404.1)
- OS version: Windows Server 2016 Standard x64

The same code runs on other servers without issues.

P.S. I saw this link, but it refers to an older version of PS: [Invoke-Sqlcmd : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OutputAs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393625/invoke-sqlcmd-a-parameter-cannot-be-found-that-matches-parameter-name-outputa)

Comment: It's likely the same problem as in the linked post - you're running the version of `Invoke-SqlCmd` that's part of `SQLPS`, rather than [the one from the `SqlServer` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

Comment: Are you, by any chance, running the above in as a SQL Server Agent task? If so, if you run `sqlps -Command "Invoke-SqlCmd -?"` can you see the `OutputAs` switch in the output? (or alternatively, run `sqlps` and then `Invoke-SqlCmd -?` once you are in the shell).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks - I've tried running it both from a powershell window and from the PS IDE, which result in the same errors as above.  I also downloaded the module (`save-module -name SqlServer`) and pointed `$env:PSModulePath` to the directory.  I don't think I'm pointing to the SQLPS version, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks - Neither command shows the `OutputAs` switch.

Comment: Then there is your problem, the shell that the command is being run is does *not* support the `OutputAs` switch.

Comment: @wmeitzen, try `Import-Module -Verbose -Force c:\path\to\your\saved\SqlServer\module\dir`

Comment: Have you tried module-qualifying the command yet? i.e.: `Import-Module SqlServer` followed by `SqlServer\Invoke-Sqlcmd ...`